# Can an adjacency matrix A of a graph $G $(of $100$ connected vertices) have at least $1$ $0$ entry in all of its powers $(A_1, A_2, A_3, ...)$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Conceptually, this means for any $A^k$ (with $k$ being a natural number obviously), there's going to be a pair $(i, j)$ with $0$ walks of length k from $i$ to $j$.

How do we go about proving such thing could or couldn't exist?

Comment: Hint:  Consider first, two vertices $a,b$ connected by an edge.  All the paths from $a$ to itself have even length and all the paths from $a$ to $b$ have odd length.

Comment: @lulu so, since vertices are connected in this graph, a and b have to have odd length, since 0 isn't odd, the path from a to b can never be 0?

Comment: I don't understand.  Work out the two vertex case in detail.  What is the adjacency matrix $A$?  What is $A^k$ for each $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ just be a straight line graph with $100$ vertices numbered from $1$ to $100$ in order along the line.

Then in $(A^{2n})_{12}=0$ and $(A^{2n+1})_{11}=0$.

Comment: can u please tell me how u got to this?

Comment: You were right with your 'conceptual' comment. The $(A^{2n})_{12}=0$ result is simply saying that to get from 1 to 2 will always take an odd number of steps. So all odd powers have a zero.

Comment: You might like to think of it as this:- To get from 1 to 2 by a sequence of single steps we must always go right one more time than we go left. Therefore it's an odd number of steps in total.